# Why does "scalar" appear like this when I cast json_decode() (in non-associative mode) to an object?

Tags: php, json

While doing some code refactoring I momentarily ended up in a situation where I was basically doing the (somewhat abstracted-out) equivalent of

```
$data = (object)json_decode('"test"');
```

Of course I understand `json_decode()` generates objects on its own unless `assoc` is false. (Incidentally I got into this situation because I was in the middle of moving some format processing code around, and I hadn't yet realized one of my `(object)` casts was now redundant.)

But... when this happened, PHP decided that `$data` contained:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [scalar] => test
)
```

***Wat.***

`scalar`?!

Last I learned, `"test"` is a *string*, so it seems more than one pile of things has fallen over internally here. Or is this unintuitive yet intended design?!

I have of course removed the `(object)` and things work exactly how I intended now. So there's no bug here per se. I just wanted to understand what just happened.

Here you go, in case you want to join in the headscratching:

```
php -r 'print_r((object)json_decode("\"test\""));'
```

I'm using 7.0.25.

Comment: What response did you expect?

Comment: @Marwelln: Now I understand casting non-array/null to object will create an object with a `scalar` key. I thought `json_decode` and/or some other component(s) had significantly broken and tried to label the array per a converted integer value... or something. I wasn't sure.

Comment: @Marwelln: To be honest, the reason I came here - and that I thought my crazy interpretation of the situation might have been even remotely possible - is due to legitimate "wat O.o" moments I've had with PHP in the past - the SQLite extension can sometimes run statements twice; the `socket_*` and `stream_*` functions don't make it possible to handle certain network failure modes; all of the process-execution functionality can return bogus return values; PHP cannot handle large files unless CFLAGS are set manually; the list goes on.

Comment: @Marwelln: While I had no misconception that I might've been barking up the wrong tree here, I was preparing myself to add yet another "O.o" to the list. I'm genuinely glad that I'm wrong and that this is a language design feature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This is exactly what the manual specifies will happen when casting a scalar type (i.e. int, string, float, boolean) to an object.](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.object.php#language.types.object.casting)

> If an object is converted to an object, it is not modified. If a value of any other type is converted to an object, a new instance of the stdClass built-in class is created. If the value was NULL, the new instance will be empty. An array converts to an object with properties named by keys and corresponding values. Note that in this case before PHP 7.2.0 numeric keys have been inaccessible unless iterated.
>
> **For any other value, a member variable named scalar will contain the value.**

```
$obj = (object) 'ciao';
echo $obj->scalar;  // outputs 'ciao'
```

Comment: TIL. I had no idea. There's always a part of the manual you haven't read :D thanks for the education.